# vertical alignment some fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-platform

With some fonts have a problem. For example Neo Sans W1G. On different platforms, they have different vertical alignment. 
On Linux and Mac OS font rises to the top, but on windows it looks fine. I'm testing on browsers chrome, safari and firefox. 
Maybe someone else encountered this problem?

```
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 50px;
```

screenshot
http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=76735ce51bbdb8b7a11f4378c2e667c8

Comment: may be different font faces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by font format history and Microsoft/Apple/Adobe format wars, different font formats included different metadata fields to compute line height, and the situation was "fixed" by allowing to declare all of them in later formats. (different metadata = different fields with different definitions, not same fields with different names)

Basically any software can pick and choose any of the line height computation algorithms as long as the corresponding metadata is present in the font. Unless the font creator was very careful with the values he put in this metadata all the algorithms won't produce the same value. Most font authoring tools will try to fill all the possible variants of metadata in order to "work" on as many platforms as possible. They rely on the font author to check the values they put there before release. Since most font creators only test a specific platform weird things happen when you try to use their fonts in a cross-platform context.

Likewise, depending on its original platform an app will prefer one algorithm over others for legacy compatibility reasons.

Some webfont platforms propose to "fix" legacy fonts but you need to have a license to modify the font files.

IIRC the typography CSS workgroup wanted to replace all of this with a new unified algorithm, I don't think they have finished yet and when they will have I'm not sure it will actually replace legacy methods instead of adding one more possibility to the mix.

Better, not to make your design depend on an exact value here.